# jQuery functions run in background?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a lot of elements (~1,500) of the same class on it, and when I execute

```
$(".pickrow").addClass("vis");
```

it takes a second or two for the page to reflect the changes.  So that users aren't thinking the page was stuck, I'd like to pop-up a small message using:

```
$("#msgDiv").show();
$(".pickrow").addClass("vis");
$("#msgDiv").hide();
```

But the msgDiv never shows.  If I remove the `$("#msgDiv").hide();` the msgDiv appears simultaneously with the application of the added class (after the 1 or 2 seconds it took to add the class).

It seems like the jQuery functions get pooled and run together without any screen updates until they have all completed.

How can I get the msgDiv to appear while the `$(".pickrow").addClass("vis");` is processing?

Here's a **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PPH_/SpF5h/)**

Comment: Would you mind posting a Fiddle? My second question... Is #msgDiv hidden initially? That might explain why it won't show... It gets hidden again.

Comment: What does your new class do? You might be able to set up a defered reference to it that will hide your message when the calculatedStyle matches.

Comment: Why do you have so many elements that need changing?

Comment: @ putvande - it's a table with tons of data.  The table defaults to displaying summerized data. Clicking a row will display the detail rows for that summary (usually 5 - 20 detail rows per summary row).  I added a button so that all summaries would be expaned at once, so you don't have to click on every summary row.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to delay the hide by a few seconds.

```
$("#msgDiv").show();
$(".pickrow").addClass("vis");
setTimeout(function(){ $("#msgDiv").hide(); },2000);
```

Or using jQuery's animations queue for timing:

```
$("#msgDiv").show();
$(".pickrow").addClass("vis");
$("#msgDiv").delay(2000).hide(1); //must make it at least 1 ms to go into the queue
```

Comment: This is a horrible recommendation, you're using javascripts plain setTimeout instead of jQuery's delay, and recommending a constant timer for something that's of unknown time.

Comment: Ok, he said he wants the item to hide it after 1-2 seconds. This is an answer to the question, not rocket science.

Comment: In that case propose `$("#msgDiv").delay(2000).hide(1);` then, don't mix vanilla js and jQuery unless you have to.

Comment: This would work. The setTimeout would add the hiding of the message to the javascript event queue to be executed. if the .addClass finishes before 2 seconds, then great - hide the message after that time (any quicker might look like a flicker). If .addClass takes longer, the function won't execute until control is returned back to the JS event queue. OP can convert the idea to jquery syntax. +1 from me.

Comment: But that still doesn't make the msgDiv appear while the page is "thinking".  It's the second or two that looks like nothing is happening that I want to inform the user that something is.  Otherwise they click the "show/hide" button (which toggels the visibility of the 1500 elements) again, and then it ends up undoing what they wanted.

Comment: @Michael_B It does if you use my version, animations under 1/100 seconds are skipped, but still get affected by delay and go on the animations queue. http://jsfiddle.net/Pggp2/2/

Comment: Ok, I see. (I didn't know that about animations)

Answer (score 2):

You can go with this approach also

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3MYxQ/1/)**

```
$(document).on("click",".btn",function(){
    $(".msg").show("fast",function(){
        $(".pickrow").addClass("vis");
   var interval = setInterval(function(){

        var picLength = $(".pickrow").length;
        var visLength = $(".vis").length;

        if(picLength == visLength){
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(".msg").hide();
        }

    },500);
});
```

});

Comment: That only appears to work because the time it takes to apply the `.addClass('vis')` is less than the 500 ms you chose.  Here is a **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PPH_/SpF5h/)** that uses your suggestion but still shows the problem - When the data to be processed is a lot more detailed

Answer (score 0):

I think if you simplify the code, you would find that it is much more responsive and probably not require the loading message.  In your code, you check every single element in an if statement.  Rather than do that, you can check one value, then update all of them accordingly.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/3A4qU/

I made a single change to your HTML to set the initial value of the input button to "Show Details".  Then in the following code, you can just check whether the value is Show Details and remove the class that hides the .pickrow and update the value of the button to be "Hide Details" (which is better feedback for the user anyway).  Likewise, you can add the .hid class to the pickrow if the button value is not "Show Details".  This will also normalize all of the classes regardless if some were individually hidden or shown.

```
$('#showhide').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).val() === 'Show Details') {
        $('.pickrow').removeClass('hid');
        $(this).val('Hide Details');
    } else {
        $('.pickrow').addClass('hid');
        $(this).val('Show Details');
    }    
});
```

Comment: I just read your comment that you have other buttons to show/hide individual rows... so the use of toggle above isn't ideal, as it will hide rows that are already shown.

Comment: Edited my answer so it's not using toggle.